# How do I set a shell script as a default application

Tags: shell-script, launcher

I am using Manjaro linux with i3wm. I want a shell script (which takes the file path as argument) to be the default application for opening .ppt files. I have added the script to path, but it does not show up in the list of applications in Nautilus, nor in [selectdefaultapplication](https://github.com/sandsmark/selectdefaultapplication). How do I set it up so that whenever I double click on a ppt file, or open it through rofi, it runs the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a .desktop file for the script and put it in `~/.local/share/applications/`. And you add it as default application.

Comment: I have `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications/` but the program started by the script runs for a few seconds on the bottom panel only and then disappears. Would you mind taking a look at: [_How to set a shell script as KDE file association_](https://superuser.com/q/1828467/516482).